# BaseX RESTXQ "hello world" example

Tags: rest, basex

I'm strugging to get started with the BaseX RESTXQ API.

I've downloaded and installed the latest version of BaseX for Windows. I have started the BaseX Server by clicking the "BaseX Server (Start)" icon that the BaseX installation adds to the Windows Start menu.

It appears that I need to create a file with an `.xqm` extension (eg. `hello.xqm`) and put it somewhere.

1. Do you have a minimal "hello world" type example file eg. `hello.xqm` to get me started?
2. Where should I put the `hello.xqm` file so it runs on my default installation of BaseX?
3. Where do I need to point my browser to and what should I see if it works?

Thanks.

Comment: what does your `hello.xqm` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We noticed that the web files in Version 7.3 of the Windows version of BaseX were accidentally moved to the bin directory. You'll find a pre-packaged RESTXQ module in the latest (stable) snapshot of BaseX:

http://files.basex.org/releases/latest/

You may also have a look into the BaseX RESTXQ documentation:

http://docs.basex.org/wiki/RESTXQ

Comment: Yes the `BaseX/http` directory was empty and `basex.svg`, `index.html`, `restxq.xqm` and `style.css` were in the `BaseX/bin` directory. Moving them to the `BaseX/http` directory solved the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found really nice slide for creating web application with restxq in BaseX. please see on this paper:

http://files.basex.org/publications/xmlprague2013/slides/Andy-Bunce-BaseX-User-Group-Talk.pdf

also here is very good example

https://github.com/siserle/blog-example (thanks to siserle)